# How to debug memory leak in python application

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks

I have written a python code which basically scans for all the files within a folder (mining some text out of all the files present within that folder)

1. If folder is small i.e no of files are less , then ram usage is low
2. If no of files is beyond 100k , memory gets close to 80-90%

basically doing -

for path,subdirs,files in os.walk(folder):
    process files
    based on some logic

once program finishes ram goes down.
But for bigger folders it keep growing , I checked all variables declared etc but not able to debug memory leak.

Wanna check which variable or instance keeps on growing.
Tried using mem_top , pympler etc , but not much helpful in debugging.

Comment: your process_files_based_on_some_logic is probably the i ssue

Comment: @JoranBeasley - any suggestions on how to debug ?

Comment: mem_top? pympler? cprofile(maybe)? ... but you already tried those you said ... but thats what i would use